# Extracting a function that contains a continue statement

Tags: function, loops, break, continue

This is just something I'm curious about.
Consider this piece of code:

```
int i;

int main()
{
    while (i < 100) {

        // skip 10 numbers if current number is prime
        if (is_prime(i)) {
            i += 10;
            continue;
        }

        printf("%d ", i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Imagine the `if` part were longer, and I'd like to extract into a new function for readability purposes.
I'm tempted to do something like this:

```
int i;

void skip_ten_if_prime();

int main()
{
    while (i < 100)  {
        skip_ten_if_prime();
        printf("%d ", i);
        i++;
    }
}

void skip_ten_if_prime() {
    if (is_prime(i)) {
        i += 10;
        continue;
    }
}
```

This wouldn't work, though, since obviously the `continue` statement is now outside of the loop (and has no way of knowing *what* to continue, so to speak). The same would apply to `break`, actually.

Here's what I'd like to know:

- **Is my premise flawed?** In other words, is it wrong to want to extract a function inside a loop like this?
- If not, **what is the best way to do that?** I can think of a couple of ways, but I'm not sure which one's the way to go if any.
  I could introduce a global variable like `do_continue` which is set in the function and checked inside the loop (or a member variable if this were object oriented), but that seems like bad practice to me.
  Another way would be to have the function return a boolean and check that inside the loop. That would result in something like `if (skip_ten_if_prime()) continue;`, and I'm not sure that's desirable either because the function was never meant to return anything, and with function names like `handle_foo()` (or `handle_bar()`) it might not be obvious what is being checked.

I tend to do way too much exposition for simple questions like this, so apologies if I was being unclear anywhere.

Comment: IMO ... making use of another function that checks the boolean result from the first will be a better approach from the above two.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `skip_ten_if_prime` can return bool value. True if `i` is prime, and false in another case. And then by returned value you can decide if you need to execute continue statement or not.

Additionaly it's not a good idea to create a global variables for this purpose. Consider passing reference or pointer of `i` variable to `skip_ten_if_prime` function instead.

Here is an example how your problem could be solved.
    int i;

```
bool skip_ten_if_prime();

int main()
{
    while (i < 100)  {
        if(skip_ten_if_prime()) {
           continue;
        }
        printf("%d ", i);
        i++;
    }
}

bool skip_ten_if_prime() {
    if (is_prime(i)) {
        i += 10;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Well yeah, the code I posted is really just an example. I *am* taking away from this though that of the two approaches I suggested the latter is desirable, and that there's probably no better approach, so thanks for that.